# Regex to split location in R?

Tags: r, regex, pattern-matching

I have the following locations:

```
"0.0000000.000000"
"32.09447434.821947"
```

And I want to split to make sense:

```
0.000000, 0.000000
32.094474, 34.821947
```

I am using the following regex pattern:

```
"\\d{1,}.\\d{6}"
```

and various split functions, please advise what I am missing, I can't split it to 2 coordinates values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may extract them with

```
x <- c("0.0000000.000000", "32.09447434.821947")
regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\d+\\.\\d{6}", x))
[[1]]
[1] "0.000000" "0.000000"

[[2]]
[1] "32.094474" "34.821947"
```

Note that you should escape the dot to match a literal dot and `{1,}` is equal to the `+` quantifier.

Also, the same result can be obtained with

```
stringr::str_extract_all(x, "\\d+\\.\\d{6}")
```

Comment: Thanks for the options Wiktor!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `strsplit` with a regex lookaround

```
strsplit(str1, "(?<=\\.[0-9]{6})", perl = TRUE)
#[[1]]
#[1] "0.000000" "0.000000"

#[[2]]
#[1] "32.094474" "34.821947"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("0.0000000.000000", "32.09447434.821947")
```

Comment: please be so kind and explain the first part  ?<=. Does it mean I don't know how many digits will be there before the dot?

Comment: @steves It is a positive regex lookbehind which matches the pattern inside the brackets (`(?<=...)`) i.e. a dot (`\\`) followed by 6 digits) and split at the junction of the next character

Comment: @steves  If we want to split at say 0 after the pattern `strsplit(str1, "(?<=\\.[0-9]{6})0", perl = TRUE)` it matches the zero and look behind to check the pattern inside the brackets to split at 0